# Phpunit load database dump at beginning

Tags: database, phpunit, dump

I just started  with phpunit and i am testing forms if they are right coded.
There I use not only one phpunitfile, it is more ca. 10 .
Now I want to know, is it possible to load a database dump before phpunit starts running all these files or before every file?

Comment: If every test case modify the database, you should reload at every scenario, seet phpunit hook method `setup` (executed before every test method) of `setupBeforeClass` (executed before all the methods only one time). Hope this help